# Select only if related entities column contains specific value

Tags: sql, database, select, sql-server-2008-r2

I having a hard time figuring out a sql query.
I want to pick all companies that only has licenses with a name containing "Test".

```
Company                     License
|pkId|Name      |           |pkId|CompanyId|Name        |
-----------------           -----------------------------
|1   |Microsoft |           |1   |1        |License Test|
|2   |Apple     |           |2   |1        |Commercial  |
                            |3   |2        |License Test|
                            |4   |2        |License Test|
```

So, in the example Microsoft has 2 licenses. One test and one commercial
so I don't want that company.
But all of Apples licenses are test licenses so I want to select Apple.

What I'm thinking of is:

```
SELECT Company.Name, COUNT(Company.Name) 
FROM Company INNER JOIN  License ON License.CompanyId = Company.pkId
WHERE License.Name LIKE '%Test%'
GROUP BY Company.Name
```

to get how many rows containing "Test" for each company and compare it to

```
SELECT Company.Name, COUNT(Company.Name) 
FROM Company INNER JOIN  License ON License.CompanyId = Company.pkId
GROUP BY Company.Name
```

And if there is no difference in the count, I have a company with only test licenses.
But I have no idea how to but it all together or if there is a better way.

Comment: When asking database related question you should always specify which particular database system you are using; capabilities and solutions differ between them.

Comment: You'r right. Edited it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to subtract one set from another (that is, return one set, but without rows that appear in another set), and this is what the [EXCEPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28SQL%29#EXCEPT_operator) (or MINUS in Oracle) operator does. This query should give you what you want:

```
SELECT c.pkId, c.Name FROM Company c
INNER JOIN License l ON c.pkId=l.CompanyId
WHERE l.Name LIKE '%Test%'
EXCEPT
SELECT c.pkId, c.Name FROM Company c
INNER JOIN License l ON c.pkId=l.CompanyId
WHERE l.Name NOT LIKE '%Test%'
```

There are other ways of doing this, but this should be the most straightforward.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/31894).

Comment: Thank you! Works the way i wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

This is an attempt if it is SQL Server Database:-

```
declare @company table (pkid int, name varchar(20))

insert into @company values (1,'microsoft')
insert into @company values (2,'apple')

declare @license table (pkid int, companyid int, name varchar(20))

insert into @license values (1,1,'license test')
insert into @license values (2,1,'comm')
insert into @license values (3,2,'license test')
insert into @license values (4,2,'license test')

select * from @company
select * from @license

select c.name
from @license l
inner join @company c
on c.pkid = l.companyid
where l.companyid not in
(select companyid from @license l1
where l1.name not like '%test%')
group by c.name
```

Answer (score 0):

If all companies have at least one license, the following will work.  It checks if there is any license that is not for "test":

```
SELECT c.Name 
FROM Company c LEFT JOIN
     License l
     ON l.CompanyId = c.pkId AND l.Name NOT LIKE '%Test%'
WHERE l.CompanyId IS NULL
GROUP BY c.Name;
```

I think, though, that I prefer to do this with `exists` and `not exists` clauses:

```
select c.*
from company c
where exists (select 1
              from License l
              where l.CompanyId = c.pkId and l.Name LIKE '%Test%'
             ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from License l
                  where l.CompanyId = c.pkId and l.Name not LIKE '%Test%'
                 );
```

This says that at least one row with "test" exists and none without.

Or, you can phrase this as a `having` clause in the aggregation query:

```
select c.Name 
from Company c inner join
     License l
     ON l.CompanyId = c.pkId
group by c.Name
having sum(case when l.Name like '%Test%' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when l.Name not like '%Test%' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Comment: The first query seems to return the opposite result (it got Microsoft, but not Apple with the example data).

Comment: @jpw . . . That is really weird.  Somehow, I just didn't finish that query.  It is now the `left join` with `where` so it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your example and my results are (2, 1) for the first query, and (2,2) for the second.

```
SELECT COUNT(License.Name) AS counter, Company.Name
FROM Company INNER JOIN License ON License.CompanyId = Company.pkId
WHERE License.Name LIKE '%Test%'
GROUP BY Company.Name
HAVING counter = (SELECT MAX(counted) FROM (SELECT COUNT(l.Name) AS counted FROM License AS l WHERE l.name LIKE '%Test%' GROUP BY l.companyid) AS co)
```